# How to quick update machine learning models to new training data in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

My question is how to update learning model in real time? for example I want to update model every 5 minute when new data is available without retraining the model completely again (due to heavy server load). Is there some packeges in R for doing this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like an infinite while loop with a timer?

Comment: @user2974951, I imagine it as a function in some package, like in the caret "update.train", which can just little update the model without full re-training, but unfortunately "update.train"  works only for the updeting tuning params. But I need to update training data in the model.

Comment: Updating a model by adding new results to it without altering all the previous results  is only available to some specific algorithms. You need to give us specifics.

Comment: now I'm using RF,  for binary classification, using nominal and numeric predictors in the model

Comment: If you are using the `randomForest` package then you can use the `grow()` function from the package.

Comment: As I see, that function increases number of trees. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it can only do so on the same data, so it doesn't apply to your case.

Answer (score 1):

In R the `h2o` package has a possibility to do this, but only with GBM, Deep learning and DRF (Distributed random forest). In these models there is the option to select specify a checkpoint:

> The checkpoint option allows you to specify a model key associated
>   with a previously trained model. This will build a new model as a
>   continuation of a previously generated model.

But check the help files because there are restrictions on what you can additionally train and which hyper parameters cannot be changed when you do this.

More info can be [found here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/checkpoint.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will read it